# Difference in Gamma Distributions have Poisson?

Tags: poisson-distribution, stochastic-processes, gamma-distribution

Today I learned about a Double Stochastic Process for the first time.

Apparently a Cox Process is a Double Stochastic Process. Here is my attempt to summarise this:

Cox Process: A point process (I think this means the output of the process is a point) where the intensity function, $\lambda_1(t)$, is itself a random process.

1. Example of Cox process : Assume $\lambda_1(t)$ is a Gamma process (stochastic process) where each increment is a gamma-distributed random variable. Suppose it has shape parameter $k=2$ and scale parameter $\theta=1$.

Then, the intensity function $\lambda_1(t)$ at time $t$ can be represented as a sum of $t$ independent gamma random variables:

$$\lambda_1(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{t} X_i$$

where each $X_i$ is ~Gamma( shape $k=2$, scale $\theta=1$)

2. Example of application: Cox process up to time $T=10$.

Generate the intensity function $\lambda_1(t)$, and then for each time $t$, generate a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda_2(t)$:

$$
\lambda_1(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{t} X_i, \quad X_i \sim \text{Gamma}(k=2, \theta=1)
$$
$$
N(t) = \text{Poisson}(\lambda_1(t))
$$

$N(t)$ is the Cox Process.

3. Steps Involved for simulating Cox Process up to time T:

- Step 1: Generate Random $X_i$ from $ \text{Gamma}(k=2, \theta=1)$
- Step 2: Calculate the cumulative sum for $\lambda_1(t)$
- Step 3: Generate a random number from $\text{Poisson}(\lambda_1(t))$ : this will be the number of events which will happen up to time=t. Subtracting $N(t+i) - N(t+j)$ will tell you how many events took place during the interval $i-j$

I am not sure why Poisson Distribution is used here. Is it because differences in Gamma Random Variables have Poisson Distribution?

Comment: Searching our site for [gamma poisson process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=gamma+poisson+process) produces many answers.

Comment: so its arbitrarily? no real reason as to why cox process is based on poisson?